# how to get report parameter by pasing multiple paramters values SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

i m using ReportingService2005 webservice to get report parameter , but i want to get parameter by passing multiple values for same parameter 
like i have 3 values of one field to which i want to filter other parameter record

GetReportParameters(ReportPath, null, false, values, null);

here value is ParameterValue object , and this have name and value property

that means it take one value for each parameter

can any one tell me how can i set multiple parameter values in GetReportParameters()

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Create an array of ParameterValue objects, and pass this array to the GetReportParameters method.**

[This article](http://odetocode.com/code/123.aspx) has information on using GetReportParameters to retrieve values of cascading parameters.